# How to change date format from yyyy-MM-dd to dd-MMM-yyyy

Tags: java, date

I am retrieving date from database. Datatype is'date' with date format 2015-12-16.

I need to set that date to my bean class variable.Datatype is Date with format 16-Dec-2015

These are the date formats i am using

```
      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
              SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

              Date date = null;
              String formatteddate = null;

                try {
                    formatteddate = formatter.format(rs.getDate("dol"));
                    System.out.println("formatteddate=============="+formatteddate);
                    date = formatter.parse(formatteddate);
                    System.out.println("date========="+date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


              joborderbean.setDol(date);
```

formatteddate==============15-Dec-2015

I want to display the above format i.e,15-Dec-2015. But it is diplaying the below format

date=========Tue Dec 15 00:00:00 IST 2015

Please help me

Comment: a Date is a Date object - it does not have any formatting.  Sorry whats you question?

Comment: `formatter.format(date);`?

Comment: `Date` doesn't have a format and nor should you be worrying about. Get the value from the database in the form of `java.sql.Date` and simply use it.  When you need to display it, then worry about the format

Comment: Yes i need to display that date in dd-MMM-yyyy format.

Comment: Could you explain *I need to set that date to my bean class variable.Datatype is Date with format 16-Dec-2015*? Simply because as MadProgrammer pointed out that the `java.util.Date` does not have a format in itself.

Comment: how are you retrieving the date from database and how are you trying to store it in the variable?

Comment: Can u please see my edited post

Answer (score 1):

Do like following:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String dateformat=fromatter.format(mysqldate);
System.out.println("first date format"+ dateformat);
SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateformat1=formatter1.format(mysqldate);
System.out.println("second date format"+dateforamt1);
```

also you can edit the sql fired to get the result like

```
 select DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%Y-%b-%d')
```

and

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%d-%b-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `Resultset` objects `getDate` method return a `java.sql.Date` object. So in order to store the Date in the `date` object use :

```
date = rs.getDate("dol");
```

instead of the code:

```
formatteddate = formatter.format(rs.getDate("dol"));
System.out.println("formatteddate=============="+formatteddate);
date = formatter.parse(formatteddate);
System.out.println("date========="+date);
```

now in order to test the date you can use:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
System.out.printLn("date========="+formatter.format(date));
```

This will give you the required output.

The last output you are getting because of the code `System.out.println("date========="+date);` Here the `toString` method of the `date` object is getting called which has a default as in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) as :

> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>
> ```
> dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
> ```
>
> where:
>
> - dow is the day of the week (Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat).
> - mon is the month (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec).
> - dd is the day of the month (01 through 31), as two decimal digits.
> - hh is the hour of the day (00 through 23), as two decimal digits.
> - mm is the minute within the hour (00 through 59), as two decimal digits.
> - ss is the second within the minute (00 through 61, as two decimal digits.
> - zzz is the time zone (and may reflect daylight saving time). Standard time zone abbreviations include those recognized by the method parse. If time zone information is not available, then zzz is empty - that is, it consists of no characters at all.
> - yyyy is the year, as four decimal digits.